# Conditional Formatting - how to set range for "one condition per row"?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I thought I understood Conditional Formatting, but I'm having trouble applying it.

I have a table like this:

```
J   F   M   A   M   J   J   A   S   O   N   D
317 876 781 735 490 790 569 922 976 923 259 270
440 734 788 729 337 876 641 735 892 906 463 872
773 863 537 538 389 988 404 599 459 976 235 891
772 134 845 218 669 414 352 276 965 677 723 342
343 283 251 703 420 430 355 485 537 723 838 199
354 846 503 448 196 249 237 503 309 291 432 807
259 126 213 254 577 688 195 681 658 407 637 827
293 333 562 242 504 335 276 675 173 592 388 418
```

And I'd just like to highlight, via Green Fill, the `Max()` in each row.

I highlighted my range, keeping the top left (`317`) as my active cell. Then I tried this formula:
`=max($A2:$L2)`, but this just highlights my entire table:

[image: ScreenShot]

If I highlight row 2, use `=Max($A2:$L2)`, then the whole row gets highlighted...I've even tried using the `Top 10` default rule, changing to top 1, but no avail.

What I *can* do, is use the `Top 1`, on a single row, then paste that formatting down.  However, I'd like to get a single formula, if possible, so I can avoid having hundreds of CF formats in the "CF rules box".

Thanks for any ideas. I'm sure it is a simple fix, I'm just overthinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the formula you're looking for is:
`=A2=MAX($A2:$L2)`

[image]

This compares the value of the cell to the max value of the row.  When equal, the formula evaluates to `TRUE`.

Comment: Aahaha, yessss. It's so simple!  Thanks a lot :D   For the record, some of my rows are entirely `0`, so the whole row gets highlighted. I adjusted the formula and finished with: `=AND(A2=MAX($A2:$L2),A2>0)`

Comment: Thinking out loud:  The reason it wasn't working with just `Max()` is because it was "saying", in the range A2:L2, just get the max value. This is `TRUE`. Thus, the whole range is highlighted, since `=Max([any range really]) will always return `true`. I needed your `A2=max()` logic to fix that up.

Comment: @BruceWayne Glad to hear it's working!  Good call on the >0 check, too.  I never really understood why it accepts things like "=max([range])" since that doesn't return a boolean, but such is life.

Comment: Carl, if you're interested I added an explanation of Conditional Formattings's behavior in evaluating `MAX` as a boolean. I don't know how long it will be permitted to linger as an answer, but hopefully is of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer to the question asked in the comments, i.e., what's going on with evaluating `MAX` to TRUE or FALSE in conditional formatting.

In Excel zero evaluates to FALSE and all other numbers to TRUE (or something like that). So for instance `=NOT(NOT(0))` evaluates to FALSE.

When you entered your `MAX` formula in conditional formatting it will evaluate to TRUE unless the `MAX` formula result is zero, in which case it results in FALSE:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Doug, but isn't 0 evaluating to FALSE there?

Comment: @CarlKevinson, woops, I wrote the opposite of what I meant. Thanks. It's fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for this @DougGlancy!